# How can i display & position text in my NavBar using Inkwell in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navbar

I am using InkWell for my Custom Navigation Bar Icons as shown below. But i'm trying to position the text right below the Icons in the text, and looks like i'm finding it difficult to get around it.

I've tried using TextStyle but it seem not to work.

This is the desired look. [image: Desired UI]

This is what i am getting

[image]

Below is my code snippet.

1. custom_navbar.dart

```html
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:afri_pro/modules/messages/controllers/chat_controller.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/messages/controllers/notification_controller.dart';

import 'package:afri_pro/theme/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../models/user_model.dart';
import '../dashboard/components/floating_subscription_modal.dart';
import '../dashboard/components/subscription_notice.dart';
import '../services/controllers/services_controller.dart';
import 'controllers/home_controller.dart';

class CustomNavBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  final onItemSelected;

  const CustomNavBarWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedIndex,
    required this.onItemSelected,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeController homeController = Get.find();
    MessagesController messagesController = Get.find();
    NotificationsController notificationsController = Get.find();
    ServicesController servicesController = Get.find();

    var user =
        UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(servicesController.userData.value)).user!;

    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 60.0,
            child: Obx(() => Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        onItemSelected(0);
                        messagesController.leaveRoom();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                          child: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.house_alt,
                            color: homeController.currentTab.value == 0
                                ? AppColors.secondary
                                : const Color(0xff979797),
                          )),
                    ),
                    if (user.userType != "player" &&
                        servicesController.subscription.isNotEmpty &&
                        !servicesController.loading &&
                        user.userType != "club_official")
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          onItemSelected(4);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                            child: const Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.line_horizontal_3_decrease,
                              color: Color(0xff979797),
                            )),
                      ),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          onItemSelected(1);
                          if (messagesController.selectedRoomId.value != 0) {
                            messagesController.socket.emit('joinRoom',
                                messagesController.selectedRoomId.value);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            if (messagesController.showBadge.value == true)
                              Positioned(
                                right: 0,
                                top: 5,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 8,
                                  height: 8,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color:
                                          homeController.currentTab.value == 1
                                              ? AppColors.secondary
                                              : const Color(0xff979797),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                child: Icon(
                                  CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble,
                                  color: homeController.currentTab.value == 1
                                      ? AppColors.secondary
                                      : const Color(0xff979797),
                                )),
                          ],
                        )),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          onItemSelected(3);
                        },
                        child: Stack(children: [
                          if (notificationsController.showBadge.value == true)
                            Positioned(
                              right: 6,
                              top: 6,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 8,
                                height: 8,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: homeController.currentTab.value == 3
                                        ? AppColors.secondary
                                        : const Color(0xff979797),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                              child: Icon(
                                CupertinoIcons.bell,
                                color: homeController.currentTab.value == 3
                                    ? AppColors.secondary
                                    : const Color(0xff979797),
                              )),
                          const Text(
                            'Notif',
                          ),
                        ])),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          onItemSelected(2);
                          messagesController.leaveRoom();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.gear_alt,
                              color: homeController.currentTab.value == 2
                                  ? AppColors.secondary
                                  : const Color(0xff979797),
                            ))),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. persistent_bottom_tab.dart

```html
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/messages/views/chat.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/dashboard/views/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/messages/views/notifications.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/players/views/filter_plyaer_view.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/players/views/players.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/settings/views/settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';
import 'controllers/home_controller.dart';
import 'custom_navbar.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/modules/players/controllers/players_controller.dart';
import 'package:afri_pro/routing/tab_routing.dart';

class CustomBottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomBottomTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomBottomTab> createState() => _CustomBottomTabState();
}

class _CustomBottomTabState extends State<CustomBottomTab> {
  var items = [
    const Dashboard(),
    const Chat(),
    const Settings(),
    const Notifications(),
  ];

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeController homeController = Get.find();

    PlayersController playersController = Get.find();

    return PersistentTabView.custom(
      context,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
      controller: homeController.persistentTabController,
      itemCount: items
          .length, // This is required in case of custom style! Pass the number of items for the nav bar.
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
      customWidget: CustomNavBarWidget(
        // Your custom widget goes here
        selectedIndex: homeController.persistentTabController.index,
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          if (index == 4) {
            playersController.nextPage.value = 1;
            playersController.title.value = "All Players";
            playersController.resetFilters();
            playersController.resetPlayers();
            playersController.fetchAllPlayers();
            TabRouting().pushScreen(context, const Players());
          } else {
            homeController.persistentTabController.index = index;
            homeController.updateCurrentTab(index);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Appreciate in advanced & a happy weekend :)

Comment: why do you want use inkwell?

Comment: basically the code was handed over to me from another developer and used inkwell for all the icons, if there's a better way to do it and wouldn't affect the ontap functionalities, i am in. thanks

Comment: could you please include navbar code too? so I could tell you the better alternative.

Comment: okay sir, i updated my code snippets, please let me know if you'd need something else. NB: i'm using Getx

Comment: Could you please add CustomNavBarWidget too?

Comment: i think the class of the custom_navbar.dart file is the CustomNavBarWidget sir

Comment: if there is any other widget i should provide or code snippet, please let me know sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your `custom_navbar`, change this:

```
child: SizedBox(
   width: double.infinity,
   height: 80.0,
   child: ...),
```

then in your every `InkWell` change this:

```
InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                onItemSelected(3);
              },
              child: Stack(children: [
                if (notificationsController.showBadge.value == true)
                  Positioned(
                    right: 6,
                    top: 6,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 8,
                      height: 8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: homeController.currentTab.value == 3
                              ? AppColors.secondary
                              : const Color(0xff979797),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                    ),
                  ),
                Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                    child: Icon(
                      CupertinoIcons.bell,
                      color: homeController.currentTab.value == 3
                          ? AppColors.secondary
                          : const Color(0xff979797),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  left:0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Text(
                    'Notif',
                  ),
                ),
              ])),
```

Comment: this approach didn't work for me, as i need that little circle symbol for when there is a new notification. plus it is not displaying as the desired look.

Comment: o sorry my bad, I updated my answer again, check it out

Comment: this works! but as 'notification' is a long word, most part of it gets out of visibility, is there a way i can make the word fit in properly and visible?

Comment: I updated my answer, set left:0, for Positioned too.

Comment: Thank you! it worked, though in the different icons i had to tweak the positioning and the font sizes of the text so it would fit perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My question is if you really need stack. You could always use Material widget as a replacement for a Container. Below Material use Column and in said column create icon & text.

What I see here is stack always keeps items at top 0 & left 0. Stack always keeps widget at the bottom of its children list at the top. When you have your icon positioned it gets moved down a bit and then text is kept at the top of the stack positioned at coordinates 0.

You can easily avoid that using widget tree like: Material->Inkwell->Column->your widgets like so:

```
 Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60,
          width: 40,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.question_mark, color: Colors.white,),
                Text('name', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Pasting this anywhere as a widget will give you clickable black box with inkwell with your icon and text sorted properly.

Comment: Okay thank you but please can i have practical example as shown in my code snippet, i am still a beginner at flutter and practical examples would really help sir, trying to implement but getting a lot of errors as maybe i'm not doing it right :(

Comment: It works but i get a "bottom overflowed by 27pixel" error and when i use text for the other icons, it don't just fit in well. plus i get this ugly look from the `Material()` which is different from the background style

Comment: Tit's just a working suggestion since you wanted a working example, obviously you still need to modify it to make it work in your situation. I made it as a standalone Material container with inkwell and icon with text to show you how it could be done in your situation. If I had to create bottom nav bar I'd use some premade package with the look I want to accomplish (or something similar and adjust it accordingly) ;)